# html：The following code in the Safari browser, after flipping the card, the left button cannot respond when clicked

Tags: html, css

```
<style>
    html,
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    .container {
        margin: auto;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        position: relative;
        perspective: 1000px;
    }
    .card {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transition: transform 1s;
    }
    .card.flip {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    .card .front,
    .card .back {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
    .card .front {
        background-color: #f00;
    }
    .card .back {
        background-color: #0f0;
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-between;
        padding: 10px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    button {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .button {
        position: fixed;
        top: 250px;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
</style>
```

```
<body>
    <button class="button"   onclick="document.querySelector('.card').classList.toggle('flip')">Flip card</button>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="front">Front</div>
            <div class="back">
                <button onclick="console.log('Left button clicked!')">Left</button>
                <button onclick="console.log('Right button clicked!')">Right</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The code can respond to the events of the buttons on both sides after flipping the card in browsers other than Safari. However, in Safari, the left button does not respond, while the right button works normally. How can I make the left button respond to events in Safari?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Rushita. I copied the code in an `HTML` file and opened it using Safari browser and it worked. Maybe you should check the version of the browser. I am using Safari version 17.1.

I am also attaching the  code running with console output[image: And here is the code running with console output][image: Safari Version 17.1]

Comment: My Safari browser version was 17.0, and I had the above problem. After updating to 17.1, it was fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

I checked in the safari browser. Not any issue in your code. It is perfectly working.